# Getting a list of files that were committed on a specific branch (git / Atlassian Stash)

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

How can I get a list of files (or commits) that were committed on a specific branch (where the branch is already deleted)?

For example, I create TEST-123 feature branch from master, do a few commits to it, push to my central repo, and merge back to master via a pull request. TEST-123 is deleted.

At some point in the future I need to know what files have been committed on TEST-123.

My end goal here is to be able to get the list of files that were checked in with a specific ticket (all files will be checked in on the branch named as the ticket).

Thanks in advance for any ideas / suggestions.

-Pavel

Comment: Git does not store this information.  One solution is to use a server-side push hook to attach a note to the commit with that information.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I'm trying to figure out whether Atlassian Stash has some way of doing that w/o having to write additional hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use its last merged commit id in place of the branch name, branch names are just repo-local synonyms for commit ids anyway, plus some local notes for defaults and such.

```
merge=$(git log --merges --format=%H --grep="Merge branch '$branchname'" | sed q)
```

will get that commit unless you're integrating commits to the mainline with fast-forwards (this is one reason to publish administratively-significant merges `--no-ff`),  or somebody's seriously messing with your merge commit subjects.

```
git diff-tree -r --name-status $merge^ $merge
```

will show you everything the merge changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if atlassian stash always creates a merge commit on pull request merge. But if it does then you can get your branch back from the history.

You can search the history,

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --min-parents=2 | grep <some message>
```

Once you have the SHA of the merge commit (suppose `74805e6`), you can do a lot of stuff

*check parents if there are more than 2, identify the deleted branch out of the parents accordingly*

In most cases there will be two parents in a merge commit.

**Find changes in one parent that are not in other** (Probably what you want)

```
git log 74805e6^1..74805e6^2 --name-only --oneline
```

**Bring back the old branch**

```
git checkout -b old_deleted_branch 74805e6^2
```

This will checkout the second parent of the merge commit.

**Difference between the two parents**

```
git diff 74805e6^1..74805e6^2
```

Comment: That's the thing, I have a requirement for a script to provide list of files that were changed with a specific ticket - easy simple way - w/o making user search history etc - something like a one-liner: git_show_commits TKT-12345. Unless Atlassian Stash has some built-in way of doing that, I guess the simplest way would be to use a server-side hook to store that info in something like a mysql table.

Answer (score 0):

The pull request for the merge still exists and clicking on it shows the list of affected files. You might have to install the free add-on 'All pull requests' to get back to the respective pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

Found RESTful web services to get the list of commits against a ticket:

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/3.7.0/stash-jira-integration-rest.html

Namely:
/rest/jira/1.0/issues/{issueKey}/commits